# How to simplify this pipeline and get the expected output with a space between columns?

Tags: regex, awk

I am using the below command and the output is

```
0dev/sdc
1dev/sde
2dev/sdd
```

using

```
lsscsi |
awk '{print $1,$7}' |
egrep -i "/dev/sdc|/dev/sde|/dev/sdd" |
cut -c 8-18 |
sed -e 's/]..//g'
```

but i wanted to have an output as below..

```
0 dev/sdc
1 dev/sde
2 dev/sdd
```

output of lsscsi command

```
[2:0:0:0]    disk    Msft     Virtual Disk     1.0   /dev/sda
[3:0:1:0]    disk    Msft     Virtual Disk     1.0   /dev/sdb
[5:0:0:0]    disk    Msft     Virtual Disk     1.0   /dev/sdc
[5:0:0:1]    disk    Msft     Virtual Disk     1.0   /dev/sde
[5:0:0:2]    disk    Msft     Virtual Disk     1.0   /dev/sdd
```

Comment: Why do you have case insensitive match on `egrep`? AFAIK,  it is not standard for the partition names to be uppercased

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this alternate `awk` also with much shorter regex:

```
lsscsi | awk '$NF ~ /\/sd[cde]$/ {gsub(/^\[.*:|\]$/, "", $1); print $1, $NF}'
```

```
0 /dev/sdc
1 /dev/sde
2 /dev/sdd
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
your_command | awk '/\/dev\/sd[ced]/{print substr($1,8,1),$NF}'
```

***OR***

```
your_command | awk '/\/dev\/sd[ced]/{gsub(/.*:|\]$/,"",$1);print $1,$NF}'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ lsscsi | awk -F'[]:[:space:]]+' '/\/sd[cde]$/{print $4, $NF}'
0 /dev/sdc
1 /dev/sde
2 /dev/sdd
```